# Laravel migration error on foreign key

Tags: mysql, laravel

I'm trying to create this migration:

```
public function up()
{
    // Create the `Dashboards` table
    Schema::create('dashboards', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->tinyInteger('is_public');
        $table->timestamps();
    });

    // Creates the user_dashboard (Many-to-Many relation) table
    Schema::create('user_dashboard', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('dashboard_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->foreign('dashboard_id')->references('id')->on('dashboards')->onDelete('cascade');
    }); 
}
```

When I run migration I get this error:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table 
'prestiti_protestatinet.#sql-358f_9e6a9' (errno: 150) (SQL: alter table
`dl_user_dashboard` add constraint user_dashboard_user_id_foreign foreign 
key (`user_id`) references `dl_users` (`id`) on delete cascade)
```

This works on my local environment (wampserver) but not on production (lamp). What's wrong here?

My user migration:

```
    Schema::create('users', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('password', 60);
        $table->boolean('active')->default(0);
        $table->string('confirmation_code')->nullable();
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->string('avatar')->nullable();
        $table->string('provider')->nullable();
        $table->string('provider_token')->unique()->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Comment: The error message you posted suggests that a foreign key constraint was not formed correctly.

Comment: Seems a problem with table engine type. I've not specified `$table->engine = 'InnoDB';` on my users table, that is MyIsam, probably due to  some database default settings...

Comment: I hope you did not created users table here, and also use unsigned for ids, please check that it may solve your problem

Comment: Where is your `user` table migration schema?

Comment: I've updated my question with my user migration. I think this problem is related to the database engine schema: by default database create `myisam` table but in my user_dashboard table I've specified `$table->engine = 'InnoDB';`. So should I specify Innodb on every migration?

Comment: @Tropicalista MyISAM does not have foreign key integrity check, so you have to specify the table engine to innodb. Or you can set your mysql's default engine to innodb, then you don't need to specify it in laravel. Simply add `default-storage-engine=InnoDB` into your my.cnf file.

Comment: Yes, change innodb as default engine solved my problem. Thanks!!